# Is it possible to calculate date values from last week but anchored to a specific day?

Tags: r, date, dynamic-programming

I want to dynamically use the previous week's date values (from Sunday through to Saturday) in the title of a chart.

I want to list the start date and end dates of the week.

For example:

```
Start: 22nd April 2018
End: 28th April 2018

Title: "Conversations (22nd April 2018 - 28th April 2018)"
```

If it is too complex using words - especially `nd`/`th`/`rd`/`st` - then I'm happy for it to be in `DD/MM/YYYY` format too.

Moreover, I want to anchor the dates so that no matter when I get the dates, they will always cover the previous week to those exact days.

For example, regardless of whether I run the code on Tuesday, Wednesday or Friday, it will always pick out the previous week's dates anchored to Sunday.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using a `while` argument:**

```
x1 <- Sys.Date()
x2 <- weekdays(x1)
while(x2 != "Sunday"){
  x1 <- x1 - 1
  x2 <- weekdays(x1)
  }
start_date <- x1 - 7
end_date   <- x1 - 1
```

Gives:

```
> start_date
[1] "2018-04-22"
> end_date
[1] "2018-04-28"
```

You can use this to **pass any date** and find the start and end dates of the preceding week:

```
x1 <- as.Date("2013-01-04")
x2 <- weekdays(x1)
while(x2 != "Sunday"){
  x1 <- x1 -1
  x2 <- weekdays(x1)
  }
start_date <- x1 - 7
end_date   <- x1 - 1
```

Even better, **make this into a function**:

```
week_findeR <- function(x = Sys.Date()){
  x1 <- as.Date(x)
  x2 <- weekdays(x1)
  while(x2 != "Sunday"){
    x1 <- x1 -1
    x2 <- weekdays(x1)
    }
  return(list(x1-7, x1-1))
  }
```

**Giving the output:**

```
> week_findeR()  
[[1]]
[1] "2018-04-22"

[[2]]
[1] "2018-04-28"

> week_findeR("2018-07-04")
[[1]]
[1] "2018-06-24"

[[2]]
[1] "2018-06-30"
```

Comment: This is great, thank you.  I have also found another solution which is to take the `min` and `max` values of the date range from my dataset and use those.